# Creating Single Sign-on - Logging in admin throws "Your current session has been expired."

Tags: magento2, admin, login

I am working on SSO for the Magento admin. Everything below appears to work through the `processLogin()` event (which is triggered by the controllers `execute()` method. Once `processLogin()` is returned, the user is redirected to via:

```
if ($this->adminAuthSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->getUrl('admin'));
}
```

`isLoggedIn()` returns true. However, the user is returned to the admin login page and shown the message: *"Your current session has expired."*

---

### The Code

**etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**: *Define admin routes*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="microsoft_sso" frontName="microsoft_sso">
            <module name="Etre_MicrosoftAdminSso" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**etc/adminhtml/di.xml**: *Extend adminAuthentication so that we can make some of our SSO admin routes public for authentication*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction">
        <!--
        /**
         * Make SSO login route public by extend Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication by it's original
         * plugin name of adminAuthentication
         */
         -->
        <plugin name="adminAuthentication"
                type="Etre\MicrosoftAdminSso\Plugin\Backend\PublicActions"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Controller/Adminhtml/Sso/Login.php**: *Handle SSO authentication*

Only relevant methods included.

```
class Login extends \Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    Data $ssoHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $objectFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Proxy $adminAuthSession,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig $adminConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $userFactory);
    $this->_userFactory = $userFactory;
    $this->ssoHelper = $ssoHelper;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->backendSession= $context->getSession();
    $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
    $this->adminAuthSession = $adminAuthSession;
    $this->adminConfig = $adminConfig;
    $this->appState = $appState;
    $this->configLoader = $configLoader;
    $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
}

private function processLogin(\ArrayAccess $userInfo): void
{
//        $this->_request->setPathInfo('/admin');
//        $this->appState->setAreaCode($areaCode);
//        $this->_objectManager->configure($this->_configLoader->load($areaCode));

    $user = $this->_userFactory->create()->load($userInfo->getUniqueName(), 'email');

    $session = $this->adminAuthSession;
    $session->setUser($user);
    $session->processLogin();

    if ($session->isLoggedIn() && $session->getSessionId()) {
        $session->prolong();
    }
}

...

}
```

Original, alternative `processLogin()` tried:

```
private function processLogin(\ArrayAccess $userInfo): void
{
    if (!$userInfo->hasUniqueName()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException('Microsoft failed to provide your username');
    }

    $user = $this->_userFactory->create()->load($userInfo->getUniqueName(), 'email');

    $isActive = (bool)$user->getIsActive();

    if (!$isActive) {
        throw new AuthorizationException('This account does not exist or is not currently active.');
    }

    $this->adminAuthSession->setUser($user);
    $this->adminAuthSession->processLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to inject my `$user` into `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session` so that it could be referenced by `\Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager()->processLogin()`.

My refactored code is below.

`$this->authSession` is dependency injected as `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session` and `$this-sessionManager` as `\Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionsManager`

```
/**
 * @param \ArrayAccess $userInfo
 * @return void
 * @throws AuthorizationException
 */
private function processLogin(\ArrayAccess $userInfo): void
{
    $this->loadUser($userInfo->getUniqueName())
        ->makeAdminSession();

    if (!$this->isLoggedIn()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException(__('Login Failed. You may try providing a username or password.'));
    }
}

/**
 * Create a logged in user session
 */
private function makeAdminSession(): void
{
    $this->authSession->setUser($this->user);
    $this->sessionManager->processLogin();
}

/**
 * Fetch user model by email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return $this
 * @throws AuthorizationException
 */
private function loadUser(string $email): Login
{
    $this->user = $this->_userFactory->create()->load($email, 'email');

    $userLoaded = (bool) $this->user->getId();
    if (!$userLoaded) {
        throw new AuthorizationException(__('Could not find a user associated with email %1', $email));
    }

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Check if user is logged in
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function isLoggedIn(): bool
{
    return $this->sessionManager->getCurrentSession()->isLoggedInStatus();
}
```